# How can I select the top n records per category without any duplicates in SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to select a set of recipes in a database by category. The criteria is that I need *n* number of recipes per category with no repeats. So, given a dataset `recipes`:

```
id | category
---|---------
1  | dairy
1  | eggs
1  | vegetarian
2  | dairy
2  | dessert
3  | thanksgiving
...
```

Is it possible to perform a select in such a way that my resulting dataset looks like this, where `n=1`?

```
id  | category
----|----------
1   | dairy
2   | dessert
3   | thanksgiving
```

I happen to be using Presto to query this dataset, and there are about 30 categories total. I originally thought that maybe I could do some nested `UNION` statements, but a) that would be tedious for the number of categories I have and b) I don't think it will work since each `UNION` is kind of its own thing and has no knowledge of the past. I also considered using

```
select id from (
  select id, category, row_number() over (partition by category order by id)
  from recipes)
where row_num < 2
```

which would allow me to set how many ids want back from each category, but doesn't deal with the removing duplicates.

Ultimately I have a feeling this isn't possible in SQL, and that I should move it into Python or something, but if it's possible I'm very interested to see it in action!

Comment: Repeats of what?

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  use `partition by id` instead:

```
select id, category
from (select id, category,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from recipes
     )
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `order by` only makes a difference if you want to determine *which* row you want -- the first category alphabetically for instance.

As a note:  If you wanted one id per *`category`*, then I might suggest aggregation:

```
select category, min(id)
from t
group by category;
```

Comment: If you look closely at the data, I believe your answer would generate `dairy, dairy, thanksgiving`.